# Containerized webpack-dev-server doesnt respond to file change

Tags: reactjs, docker, webpack-dev-server

I have a React app running as part of a docker-compose setup, with the following configuration:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  client:
    image: node:10-jessie
    volumes:
      - ./client:/app:rw
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
    working_dir: /app
    command: npm run dev
...
```

The `client` folder that the volume points to, has webpack.config.js and the `src` folder. When i run `docker-compose up` the application loads up fine. I can navigate to `localhost:9000` and view my app, and by navigating to the console, i can see that Live reloading is enabled.

But when i make changes to the files, which webpack-dev-server would detect and update had i run the app locally, no changes are captured. If i refresh the page manually, the changes are not detected either.

Are there anyone with any suggestions as to what i am doing wrong? I will happily provide more of my code, i just wasn't sure what else was needed to initially convey my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding the following to my webpack.config.js:

```
watchOptions: {
   ignored: /node_modules/,
   aggregateTimeout: 300,
   poll: 500
},
```